# Require password to exit app

Tags: applications, restricted-profiles

How do I make my Android tablet ask for a password when I try to exit a specific application? There should be no way to exit the application without giving the password.

Answer (score 6):

If your tablet is running Android 5.0+, you can activate "Screen Pinning" for a specific app and enable "Ask for PIN before unpinning" when activating it so that you have to unlock your phone before leaving the app.

*Screen Pinning* can be found in the *Security* Settings of Android.